# Don't use for loop to push to array alternately

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary, for-loop, jsx

I currently have some code that does this:

```
let result = []
const number

for (let i = 0; i < number; i++) {
  result.push(f(i))
  result.push(g(i))
}

return (
  <div>
    {result}
  </div>
)
```

f(i) and g(i) return a single react jsx element depending on what i is.  We will pass in i as a prop.

I am having trouble converting this to a form that does not use a for loop.  Is there a way to use map?  I would need there to be no additional div wrapped around f(i) and g(i).  In other words I CANNOT have the result equivalent to this

```
for (let i = 0; i < number; i++) {
  result.push(
    <div> 
      f(i) 
      g(i) 
    </div>
  )
}
```

The requirement of having no additional div makes it a bit hard for me to come up with a map solution or any other solution that does not use a for loop.  Do you have any ideas?

Comment: What's wrong with a for loop? otherwise, you can probably do `result.push([f(i), g(i)])`

Comment: `.map` is nice when what you want is a transformed array, but you really seem to need custom behaviour for each element in an array - this is what for loops are for, so I say stick with the loop. As a bonus, they are more efficient than `.map`, especially if you're going to have to be really clever to make `.map` work.

Answer (score 1):

You can return (or push) an array of 2 items, and then flatten by [spreading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) into [Array#concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat).

I've use [Array#from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to generate the items, but you can use a for loop, and then flatten the `result`.

```js
const f = (i) => <li key={`f${i}`}>f - {i}</li>;
const g = (i) => <li key={`g${i}`}>g - {i}</li>;

const Demo = ({ length }) => (
  <ul>
  {
    [].concat(...Array.from({ length }, (_, i) => [f(i), g(i)]))
  }
  </ul>
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Demo length={5} />,
  demo
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.js"></script>

<div id="demo"></div>
```

If you use react 16, you can return a [fragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) instead:

```js
const f = (i) => <li key={`f${i}`}>f - {i}</li>;
const g = (i) => <li key={`g${i}`}>g - {i}</li>;

const Demo = ({ length }) => (
  <ul>
  {
    Array.from({ length }, (_, i) => (
      <React.Fragment key={i}>
        {f(i)}
        {g(i)}
      </React.Fragment>
    ))
  }
  </ul>
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Demo length={5} />,
  demo
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>



<div id="demo"></div>
```